# I can't select the dates for my calendar, I don't understand what I'm doing wrong?

Tags: javascript, html, fullcalendar

problem with fullcalendar calendar. I can't select the dates for my calendar, I don't understand what I'm doing wrong?

it should appear to let me select the dates to make the reservation so for example from day 10 TO DAY 15.

I also tried to look through the various guides but nothing works (I'm using wordpress). can you help me??

code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Prenotazione</title>
    <!-- Includi le librerie di jQuery UI per il datepicker -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <!-- Includi jQuery e jQuery UI -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <!-- Includi FullCalendar 6.1.9 -->
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fullcalendar/6.1.9/main.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/fullcalendar@6.1.9/index.global.min.js'></script>
    <!-- Aggiungi il percorso corretto al file chosen.min.css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/chosen.min.css">

    <script>
        var stripePublicKey = 'pk_test_*************************************************';
    </script>
    <script src='fullcalendar/dist/index.global.js'></script>

    <style>
        /* Stili personalizzati */
        body {
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
            background-color: #f4f4f4;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }
        .calendar-container {
            max-width: 600px;
            margin: 20px auto;
            background-color: #fff;
            box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
            border-radius: 5px;
        }
        .calendar {
            position: relative;
            z-index: 1;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="calendar-container">
        <h2>Prenotazione</h2>
        <!-- Calendario FullCalendar -->
        <div id="calendar" class="calendar"></div>

        <!-- Altri input per i dati -->
        <label for="num-people">Numero di Persone (4 massimo):</label>
        <input type="number" id="num-people" min="1" max="4">

        <label for="name">Nome:</label>
        <input type="text" id="name">

        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input type="email" id="email">

        <label for="phone">Telefono:</label>
        <input type="tel" id="phone">
        <p>Prezzo Totale: <span id="total-price"></span>€</p>
        <div id="price-display"></div> <!-- Puoi aggiungerlo qui -->

        <!-- Aggiungi un pulsante per la prenotazione -->
        <button id="prenota-button">Prenota e scopri il prezzo</button>
        <label for="card-element">
            Stripe Carta di Credito o Debito
        </label>
        <div id="card-element">
            <!-- Un elemento per l'inserimento dei dati della carta di credito -->
        </div>

        <div id="card-errors" role="alert"></div>

        <button id="submit">Paga ora</button>

        <div id="confirmation-message" style="display: none;">
            <h2>Grazie per la tua prenotazione!</h2>
            <p>Riceverai un'email di conferma a breve.</p>
            <!-- Altri dettagli di conferma qui -->
        </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
            var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
            var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
                initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
                selectable: true
            });
            calendar.render();
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

it should appear to let me select the dates to make the reservation so for example from day 10 TO DAY 15.

Answer (score 1):

To select dates for the FullCalendar in your HTML document, you can make use of the "selectable" feature provided by the FullCalendar library. In your existing code, you have already enabled the "selectable" feature, but you might want to add some additional code to handle the selected dates.

Here's how you can do it:

1. In your existing code, you have initialized FullCalendar and set it to be selectable:

```js
var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    initialView: 'dayGridMonth',
    selectable: true
});
calendar.render();
```

2. To handle the selected dates, you can add an event handler that captures the selected dates and does something with them. For example, you can display the selected dates in an alert or console.log them:

```js
calendar.on('select', function(info) {
    var selectedStartDate = info.startStr; // Start date in ISO format
    var selectedEndDate = info.endStr; // End date in ISO format

    // You can now use selectedStartDate and selectedEndDate as needed.
    console.log('Selected Start Date: ', selectedStartDate);
    console.log('Selected End Date: ', selectedEndDate);

    // You can perform actions like displaying the selected dates or handling the booking process here.
});
```

This code will log the selected start and end dates when the user selects a date range in the calendar. You can customize this logic to perform any actions you need, such as booking appointments or updating the UI to display the selected dates.

Make sure to include this code within your `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {...}` block to ensure it's executed when the page is fully loaded.

Comment: You can play with my code edit in codepen the link is here https://codepen.io/lrnecgcysiam/pen/ZEVdGba